# Slide background in and out of view

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background-image

I have a button that slides the background out of view once clicked. I wish to make another button appear that, once clicked, will slide the background back into view.

I have experimented with changing the background position using `animate()`, but can't figure out what is the best way to move the background image *completely* in and out of view.

In the code below, I've tried to stay away from using "px" as a unit in order to make sure that the slide works on all screen sizes.

What would be the best way to achieve this effect? Should I use `px`, `vh`, or `%`?

```js
$("#slide").click(function() {
    $(".container").delay(100).animate({
      'background-position-y': '600%'
    }, 800, 'linear');

    $(".processHeader").delay(1000).toggle("blind", {
      direction: "up"
    }, 600);

    $(".processContent").delay(2000).toggle("blind", {
      direction: "up"
    }, 600);
});

$(".next").click(function() {
    $(".container").delay(100).animate({
      'background-position-y': '-600%'
    }, 800, 'linear');

    $(".processHeader, .processContent, .step4, .next").delay(200).fadeOut(500);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use `jQuery(window).width()` to determine the screen size, which is cross browser compatible, and pulls the current screen dimensions when it is referenced.

This should work as long as the window is not resized. If you want to also keep the image hidden when resizing occurs, you would nest this in a resize event:

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the  top, bottom, left, and right css commands. They can be animated the same way, and are used as reference for a div. For example, giving a div the style `top:0;left:0` will anchor it at the top left corner.

You can then animate it to `top:100%;left:100%` to hide it.

[Hiding a background example](https://jsfiddle.net/price1847/dzgchktp/1/)